# Peterson's Algorithm with Threads and Linked List (C language)

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, mutual-exclusion

I have the following situation:

First of all, I created an int linked list (already working, no problems with this) and I need to perform the following task:

Using 2 threads, one thread will REMOVE the first element of my list and after that this same thread must add a new element at the end of the list (the list follows a FIFO structure).

The second thread will do the same: delete the first element and add another one at the end of the list.

I need to perform this operation more than once, which is clearly done by using a loop.

When I create a thread, I use the following function:

```
for(i=0, i<NUM_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, threadBody, (void *) i);
```

in which NUM_THREADS is a variable containing the number of threads that I will use (in this case, 2), and thread is declared as:

```
pthread_t thread [NUM_THREADS] ;
```

So, my questions are:

Do I need to perform the operations I've meant before (add and delete elements on my list) on my threadBody function or this function will be empty?

In case my threadBody function isn't meant to do this operation, how do I use the threads I've created to perform those operations? Is it done by using the        pthread_join function?

Another point is that I need to use the Peterson's Algorithm in order to guarantee a mutual exclusion. How do I do it?

Comment: You question is too broad so it will be difficult to get a concise answer. But for starters: Yes, you should code the add/delete inside the threadBody. You probably should have different threadBody code for the producer and consumer (or you can use the same threadBody and pass it a parameter during creation which tells it to act as a consumer or producer). For mutual exclusion I refer you to the pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock manual pages for starters.

Comment: Peterson's Algorithm is a form of lockless multitasking developed in the early 80's. It works well on processors that existed at that time. Modern processors have a number of features that make it difficult, if not impossible, to implement lockless multitasking correctly. See for example, [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You've got your two threads so using Peterson's Algorithm is not a problem.  Just have `threadBodyAdd` and `threadBodyRemove`.  Synchronize them on the your turn/my turn variables and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

My final implementation (and working) is:

```
void *threadBody (void *id){
    long threadId = (long) id;
    int k=0;
    while(k<N){
        if(threadId == 0){
             flag[0] = 1;
             turn = 1;
             while(flag[1]==1 && turn==1);
         }
         else{
             flag[1] = 1;
             turn = 0;
             while(flag[0]==1 && turn==0);
         }
         critSection(id);
         if(threadId==0) 
            flag[0] = 0;
         else if(threadId==1) 
            flag[1] = 0;
         k++;
    }
    pthread_exit (NULL) ;   
}
```

in which critSection will be the function were the add/remove operations will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your operations over the linked list are simple. In such context, maybe would be better use lock-free programming. To read, review this [link](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/). If you are using GCC, please review the **__sync_bool_compare_and_swap** operations ([link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)). Finally, the problem of programming a lock-free linked list has been broadly studied. The next link may give you hints about it [link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bushl2/rpi/portfolio/lockfree-grape/documents/lock-free-linked-lists.pdf). Good luck!